# What package manager does image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest use?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab-ci runner script in YAML where I have a task using a

```
before_script:
 - *some_script_before

image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
```

it also uses a before_script, what in turn tries to install git via apt:

```
.some_script_before: &some_script_before
  - apt update
  - apt install -y git
```

There it fails:

```
$ apt update
/bin/sh: eval: line 159: apt: not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

So what package manager does `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest` use? So that I can install git there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release-cli image is based on Alpine Linux, so it uses the `apk` pacakge manager.

```bash
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint=""  registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest /bin/sh -c 'cat /etc/*release'
3.16.3
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.16.3
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.16"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues"
```

You can install additional packages using `apk add`

So, your gitlab job may look like this:

```yaml
myjob:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  script:
    - apk add git # install git
    # ... your other script steps here
  # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to use the gitlab distribution as a docker image to run your job in.  You need to create your own docker image, add it to your registry, and then interact with it as expected.  In order to use apt in the image, you will need to run a Linux based distribution.

Comment: The above mentioned step is the release step. It makes sense that release-cli:latest:latest was used. I use apt to install git, and git to retrieve the build_number. Am I able to remember the build_number from previous steps?

Comment: If the build_number is a variable you should be able to.  If you are using a continuous format, you can utilize $CI_PIPELINE_ID to supply a build number.  The variable is automatically accessible in your .gitlab-ci.yml